# Переход к предыдущему уровню Unity3D

Tags: unity3d

Как реализовать кнопку назад(на прошлый уровень). Универсальную. Чтобы она считывала название уровня с которого пришли на сцену где она расположена и отправляла обратно

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.html
думаю вам это поможет

Comment: а почему бы не хранить просто название прошлой сцены на каком-то обьекте. И этот обьект не выгружать при переходе со сцены на сцену из памяти. Тогда в переменную LastScene просто записывается название, а в нужный момент просто переходишь на эту сцену по названию через LoadScene()